# springfox-swagger-ui 2.9.2 not displaying swagger-ui.html page returns 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Iam using spring boot version 2.2.0.M3 , with spring-fox 2.9.2.
The issue is, iam able to view the swagger json when i visit

```
 http://localhost:8080/api/v2/api-docs
```

but iam unable to see the UI-Screen of swagger when i visit

```
 http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html
```

iam able to see swagger-ui.html from another project without a context-path.

```
 http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

in my application.properties i have set

```
 server.servlet.context-path =/api
```

My pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.M3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>example</name>
<description>example</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .excludePathPatterns("/authenticate")
                .excludePathPatterns("/**/v2/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/api/swagger-ui.html");
}
}
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableSwagger2
 public class SwaggerConfig {

 @Bean
 public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
      .select()                                  
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
      .build();                                           
}
```

}